# Корзина покупок Codeigniter хранения в таблице ci_sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста, есть таблица ci_sessions , при заходе на сайт туда записываются данные:
session_id, ip_address, user_agent, last_activity и при заполнение товаров в корзине ещё user_data.
Можно ли сделать, чтобы данные записывались в эту таблицу, не при заходе на сайт, а после авторизации например по имени сookies, либо после добавления товара в в корзину при заполнение user_data? может кто сталкивался

Answer (score 0):

В Codeigniter она сама рандомна подчищает таблицу, поэтому ничего страшного.